# Visual Studio Document Comment on Lambda

Tags: c#, visual-studio, lambda

In c# with functions you can add document comments like this:

```cs
///<summary>
///
///</summary>
///<param name=""></param>
///<returns></returns>
```

When using a normal function, this autogenerates. However, when using lambdas nothing happens. Is there a way to use document comments with lambdas?

Comment: I don't think you can.

Comment: *side note* - this is specific to visual studio, not c#. I updated the tag and title accordingly.

Comment: If your lambdas are complex enough to need documentation, you can define them as 'normal' functions and then you can get comments like you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many lambda expressions do not require you to write documentation, because it already exists.

For example, if you supply a lambda expression to a `Where` clause, function is already documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx) (although it doesn't have a ton of detail):

> predicate
>
> Type: System.Func
>
> A function to test each element for a condition.

I would suggest if you have an extension method or other sort of code that takes a lambda expression as an argument, the appropriate place to document its inputs and outputs is with the method that uses it, not the code that sets it.

On the other hand, if you need to document the internal workings of your particular implementation of the lambda (i.e. it is very complicated) I would suggest you implement it as a standard c# method that matches the signature.

Thus instead of

```
Users
.Where( r => {
    DoSomethingComplicated();
    MoreCode();
    return FinalResult();
});
```

You'd simply write

```
Users.Where( MyFunction )
```

Then define the function elsewhere:

```
/// <summary>
/// This function calls DoSomethingComplicated and MoreCode
/// </summary>
/// <returns> A Boolean specifying whether the user should be included </returns>
bool MyFunction(User user)
{
    DoSomethingComplicated();
    MoreCode();
    return FinalResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, As of now no there is no way to use `///` to document lambda or an equivalent.

**To elaborate a bit :**

normally a lambda shouldn't be too complex to understand or read.If it is it would be a better practice to extract it into a full function or method, Then you can add `///` to comment it with your summary or what you need like you normally would. So I don't think having "documentation" comment for lambda would be needed and is pretty unlikely to happen.

**Side-Note**:

Lambda is in short an anonymous function so there is not much difference in terms of performance either even if you extract it into a separate function unless you copy large object instead of passing them by ref for example.